# What Is The Authenticity Of Narrations About Prophet's صلى الله عليه وسلم Marriage With Certain Women?

Tags: seerah

I have been reading a few things regarding Prophet صلى الله عليه وسلم marriage with a woman called Fatimah bint Dhahak. She was also called by other names such as Amrah bent e Yazid bin Kilab, Aliya bint E Zubyan, and Saba bint e Sufyan, etc.

In the reports it has been mentioned that Prophet  صلى الله عليه وسلم diveroced her and Asma bint e Numan because they were suffering from leprosy. What is the authenticity of these reports? Please note that according to [THIS SOURCE](https://www.alsirah.com/%D8%B0%D9%83%D8%B1-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AE-%D9%88%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%B5-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%8A/) apparently one such report is reported to us through the following chain of narrators:-

***قال: وحدثنا عبد الله بن جعفر، عن موسى بن سعيد وابن ابى عون***

This chain of narrator could be found [HERE](http://www.shiaonlinelibrary.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/3473_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%A8-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%B0%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B0%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%8A/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_104#top) in Tabri's Al-Muntakhab Min Dhayl Al-Mudhil. Here is a screenshot of chain of narrators:-

[image]

***So, what is the authenticity of the Isnad that I mentioned above?***

This is what I found about Asma bint Numan in Sirah Ibn Hisham:-

[image]

**So, my question is: What is the authenticity of narration that says that Prophet  صلى الله عليه وسلم divorced BOTH Asma and Fatimah (Amarah) because they were suffering from leprosy?**

Comment: Al-Kilabiyah be it 'Amrah or Fatimah didn'thave leprosy. But she insulted the prophet by saying "I seek refuge by Allah from you"

Comment: @Medi1Saif - So, the narration in Tarikh At-tabari and Tabri's Al-Muntakhab Min Dhayl Al-Mudhil is not authentic, right?

Comment: No it's rather the information you've posted seems to be incorrectly interpreted or translated. Maybe you've mixed two topics here. You may read the same information in the English text posted as an Image from Sirat ibn Hisahaam. It is only Asma' who was said to have leprosy or alike.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Well, according to [THIS SOURCE](https://www.icraa.org/prophet-muhammad-unconsummated-marriages-proposals/#_ftn14) Amra bt. Yazid also suffered from leprosy. The Arabic excerpt above says,"انما طلقها رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم لبياض كان بها." Doesn't it mean that Prophet (Sallallahu'alaihi'wassalam) divorced her due to leprosy?

Comment: I see I've checked one of the sources you've linked and came to the conclusion above  and now I must say each of the linked texts in your post seem to give different information at least there seem to be differences on 'Amrah or al-Kilabiyah if it is the same person at all. However I recall that al-Kilabiyah was known for insulting the prophet and she was said to be ill minded, wikipedia even claims that for 'Asma' bint an-Nu'man. I need time to check this but actually I really have none too many work and private tasks to track to do some proper research.

Comment: Further be aware just from reading about 'Amrah in ibn Athir's Usud al_Ghabah fi Ma'arifati as-Shabah the confusion about 3 or 4 women that might have been married and divorced by our prophet is very high and the 3 cited here are among them. I posted this question: [Whom did the prophet divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35360/whom-did-the-prophet-divorce) originally to have a clearer view on the topic. But I think it is rather hard to verify the authenticity of some if not all reports.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Well, just like you, I am also seeking the answer to same question. However, I am just confirming IF Prophet (SAW) divorced any woman because of leprosy. Once again according to [THIS SOURCE](https://elkanananews.com/%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A9-%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%88/) the narration in Tarikh Tabari that say that Prophet (SAW) divorced his wife Amrah bint Yazid because she was suffering from leprosy is weak, but they never discussed the isnad of this same narration found in Tabri's Al-Muntakhab Min Dhayl Al-Mudhil.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Brother, I will really appreciate if you could answer [THIS](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/79381/help-does-hadith-say-that-nutfah-of-men-reaches-the-veins-and-muscles-of-women) question of mine. jazakallah